# Using zeroMQ for processing multiple tasks asynchronously using workers without blocking

Tags: multithreading, scala, zeromq

I have a scenario where i have server which is sending tasks for processing to different workers. I tried doing it with ZeroMQ in scala by setting up the server as a DEALER and multiple workers as DEALERS too connected to the server. But it wasn't efficient. As this was using round robin scheduling for sending the tasks. I want to do event driven scheduling of tasks without blocking any thread and i have to be sure to send tasks to those workers which are free. So how can i do that using ZeroMQ?

Comment: As stated in the answer, these sorts of questions are *explicitly* handled in the [ZMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), specifically for you in the request-reply patterns chapters. The guide is required reading for anyone who really wants to understand and deeply use ZMQ.

Comment: Yes these things have been explained in the guide but the problem is that all of the scenarios explained there are blocking except the round robin one

Comment: I want the tasks to be in a queue waiting and which ever worker becomes free then if would async request for a task and get it with no polling at the server end for requests

Comment: What guide did you read? The one I linked goes through several examples which fit your use case.

Comment: the same guide you mentioned bro, and yes they do have examples which match my use case but they use round robin for scheduling the tasks. And others use polling which is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario requires more than a `.connect()` of the ZeroMQ basic elements & put these into a more abstract communication pattern, that meets both your application needs and also serves well for the load-balancing and failure-resilience aspects of the real-world use.

You need to also propagate *<**state**>* of the [**worker**]-client back to the work-units' [**dispatcher**]-server

This may sound complicated for the first few things one tries to code with ZeroMQ, but if you at least jump to the **page 265** of the [**Code Connected, Volume 1**][*asPdf->*][1](http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3afiles/cc1pe.pdf), if it were not the case of reading step-by-step there

**The fastest-ever learning-curve** would be to have first an un-exposed view on the **Fig.60** *Republishing Updates* and **Fig.62** *HA Clone Server pair* for a possible High-availability approach and then go back to the *roots*, *elements* and *details*.

Comment: Interesting ansewr: but what document are you referrring to page 265 and Fig 62?

Comment: In the **book**, cited above, with the full URL-> to a PDF re-"print" available posted above ( for clarity, repeated also here ) ***>>>*** http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3afiles/cc1pe.pdf

Comment: "The file does not exist."

Comment: Have just checked and downloaded. It is about 20MB, so Browser may get confused. Try it's parent page ***>>>*** http://hintjens.com/blog:30 and "Save As  ... "

Comment: On my third attempt just now it does download properly.